# How do you setup a Java EE Message Driven Bean to listen to multiple queues?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, jboss-mdb

I have a Java EE message driven bean that needs to listen to multiple queues (9 different queues).  I understand that I can define 9 different message beans (one for each unique queue) and just use some common class for the business logic but it seems like there should be a better method.  The only alternative I can find is to use the ejb-jar.xml to define the 9 different beans.  This seems like a better option however with it comes the problem of the code knowing what its message destination is at run-time.  How can this be done?  I suppose reflection but is there a better method?
Just in case I wasn't clear enough I'm looking to have the same MDB listen to multiple "destination".  Here's destination being set via annotation"
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue= "queue1")

Comment: Credit to @JustAnotherProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

You can also create one base MDB without annotations, then 9 different extensions ( with no body ) annotated for each destination, but the XML strategy sounds better. You can determine the destination from the message.

Ideally, you could pick a JMS implementation that supports virtual destinations, like ActiveMQ, where a composite destination fronts multiple physical destinations.